# Problem with JQuery live and html click event

Tags: jquery

I've a problem with JQuery live() function.
I've built a share-link with a click event and if you click on the link it pops up a little div with the short URL and like buttons.
The share-link is over the pop-up div container (z-index) and if you click a second time on it the pop-up div should be disappear.
But the pop-up div should be also disappear when you click outside of the pop-up div.

here is the link to the JSFiddle (if you replace live with bind it works fine, but I need the live function). http://jsfiddle.net/Borsti/MXyGR/

And the JS-Code extra:

```
$('.share').live('click', function(event) {
        var button = $(this);
        var container = $(this).next('.sharecontainer');
        var mouse_is_inside = false;
        //alert("clicked!");
        container.toggle();
        button.toggleClass('sel');

        container.hover(function(){
            mouse_is_inside = true;
        }, function(){
            mouse_is_inside = false;
        });

        $('html').click(function() {
            if(!mouse_is_inside) {
            container.hide();
            button.removeClass('sel');
            }
        });
        return false;                
});
```

I hope you could understand me, my English is not the best ;)

Comment: Sorry, can't see any question here.

Comment: Sorry, my question is how I can do it that the pop-Up div is closed by the html-click event and the click-event of the .share-event.

Comment: You mean you want the pop up closed when clicking anywhere inside it?

Comment: No, I want close the pop-up div when I click on the share button or on any other elements except the pop-up div.
You can see here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Borsti/NFk6F/) the same example with the bind()-function instead of the live() function and it works fine. You can click on the button a second time and the div is closed or you can click anywhere in the document and the div is closed.
But when I use the live()-function I cannot close it by pressing a second time on the share button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when using `live()` for the link you also have to use it for the global `html`:

```
$('html').live("click", function() {
    if (!mouse_is_inside) {
        container.hide();
        button.removeClass('sel');
    }
});
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MXyGR/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/div-popup